# Replacing SSD - EFI and Grub arrangement - Windows + Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

Let me first explain my current disk arrangement status:

**Disk 0 HDD - 1 tb - Ubuntu here**

**Disk 1 SSD  - 128 gb - Windows + EFI partition**

I'm using both systems on dual boot and it is working fine.

However, I will replace the Disk 1 SSD with other SSD of 256 gb. This SSD also has Windows installed on it. Let's call this new SSD "disk 2". It is currently partitioned like this:

**Disk 2 SSD- 256 gb - Windows + EFI Partition..**

My problem is: the EFI partition who has the GRUB that can recognize Ubuntu is on the Disk 1.

When I remove the Disk 1 (128 gb SSD), probably the other SSD (Disk 2 - 256 gb) won't be able to recognize my Ubuntu on the boot, probably only Windows.

How do I make this Disk 2 recognize Ubuntu? Do I have to install GRUB on the Disk 2 EFI partition?

Do I have to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch all over again?

Is there a way to make the SSD recognize my current Ubuntu?

I'm confused about what to do next.

Thank you!!!! =)

Comment: This is partly why I like to have ESP on every drive & have Ubuntu/grub UEFI boot files on Ubuntu drive. But all you have to do is reinstall grub. Total reinstall which will add the /EFI/ubuntu folder to new ESP and add new entry in UEFI boot menu. You can copy /EFI/ubuntu from old SSD to new SSD's ESP, but still need to use efibootmgr to create new UEFI boot entry. If new SSD is clone, the GUID/partUUID may be same & UEFI entry would work.